# BeautifulSoup only returning first page on crawling list

Tags: python, loops, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a list of urls I'm trying to get beautiful soup to crawl through, but it only captures the first page data. Pretty sure its just an issue with how my loop is set up, but any help appreciated

```
   scripts_raw = []
   for link in random_urls:
       r = requests.get(random_urls)
       r.encoding = 'utf-8'
       tml_content = r.text
       soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

       script = soup.find('td', class_='scrtext')
       scripts_raw.append(script)
```

Comment: Did you mean ``` r = requests.get(link)``` instead? You are not using ```link``` anywhere,

Answer (score 0):

your loop is not using link, try like this:
r = requests.get(link)

Comment: Kindly use the `add comment` section to reply with discussions, doubts.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).